# Should I run Gnome keyring the only way to be to connect to wifis?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, gnome, gnome-keyring

I'm on Arch/Xfce.

I can't connect to some(!) wifi wpa2/psk hotspots when Gnome keyring isn't running. I'm on xfce and have now cheched "Run gnome services on startup". And now I'm able to connect to wifis. However, is that the only way to be able to connect?

Even when Gnome keyring isn't running, I try to connect, it disconnects immediatelly without asking me a password, then I go the setting of wifi and enter the password manually. And still it connect, now for a few seconds, and then disconnects by itself.

```
associated
[ 8502.897456] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from ee:aa:bb:cc:dd by local choice (Reason: 1=UNSPECIFIED)
```

Your suggestions, is running Gnome keyring the only way to be to connect to wifis? And why is that?

Answer (score 0):

No. If you open up a terminal you could define wireless networks and connections by using `wifi-menu` which I think is easiest and will automatically insert the Key and SSID in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa-supplicant.conf